# SSRS add in in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am quite new to sharepoint. I want to use ssrs reports in sharepoint. I came to know by google that we need to install reporting services add in.

My dev environment details are as follows.

**App Server**: SharePoint Foundation 2013, SharePoint Server 2013

**Service Pack 1 for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 (KB2880552) 64-Bit Edition**(checked from central administration upgrade and migration link)

**DB Server**: SQL Server 2012 (version: 11.0.5058) - **Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Service Pack 2 (SP2)**

so I am thinking that this would be suitable add in as per my configuration. https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=43344 (guide me if i am wrong)

I got stuck whether it has to be installed in app server or db server? do I need to reinstall any thing in the current configurations??

please suggest..thanks

Answer (score 0):

it needs to be installed on the Sharepoint server. This MSDN article will guide you through it:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905871%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396